# searching for angular directive: mailto:address print avoiding spam

Tags: javascript, angularjs, email, spam

The thing is about hiding your email from spam harvesters without disabling user from seeing it. There are small libs like http://www.bronze-age.com/nospam/ (include custom .js file and call its function), so that spam systems don't get it and the user will plainly see your address.

That's ok, but my application is in angular already and this seems a great use-case for a directive. Do you know if there is one that solves described problem? I've been looking for it, but didn't manage to find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far the best thing I've thought of is plainly using interpolations:

```
<a href="{{'mailto:'}}{{'your-name@'}}domain.com">{{'your-name@'}}domain.com</a>
```

or even:

```
<a href="{{'mailto:'}}{{'your-name'}}{{'@'}}domain.com">{{'your-name'}}{{'@'}}domain.com</a>
```

(depending on spam-bot parsing intelligence).

Google is supposed to parse SPA websites - that's cool. The browser displays it correctly (clicking on mailto link opens your mail client). But I'm not sure about spam harvesters' strength - hopefully these are still to dumb to execute angular to fetch email addresses.

So no controller/directive/service is needed in such case.